# Does MVVMCross and its plugins support iOS 6?

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

We have developed an application that uses the newest MVVMCross library and the plugins Localization, DownloadCache, File, JSON, Location, Messanger, PictureChooser, ResourceLoader and SQLite. The app supports iOS from 6.1 and up, and is updated to Xamarin Unified for 64-bit support.

Does anyone know if there is any issues between the iOS 6.1 OS and the packages listed above. Does anyone of those use iOS 7/8 API calls?

Best regards,
Kristoffer

Comment: An honest question... With Apple users known high conversion rate to the newest iOS why are you even bothering with iOS 6?  Given Apple's new rule to only allow 64 bit apps going forward can you even publish something for 6.1??

Comment: Last thing first, yes you can. Xamarins new iOS.Unified supports 32 and 64 bit architecture and our app is already out in the store. And since it quite common to let old telephones be inherited down to your children, our customer wants to support iOS 6.1 and above.

Comment: Ok not to hammer the point... Here are current iOS stats from Apple's website: iOS 8 - 77%     iOS 7 - 20%    Earlier 3%.  [source](https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/)  Just me but for less than 3% he really needs to take the costs into supporting it into account.  But to answer your question... No I don't know of any issues but then again I highly doubt developers are targeting iOS 6 at all.  Best I can say is... give it a try!